# Regular expression with the cyrillic alphabet

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have an jQuery function for word counting in textarea field. In addition its excludes all words, which are closed in [[[tripple bracket]]]. It works great with latin character, but it has a problem with cyrillic sentences. I suppose that the error is in part with regular expression:

```
$(field).val().replace(/\[\[\[[^\]]*\]\]\]/g, '').match(/\b/g);
```

Example with both kind of phrases:
http://jsfiddle.net/A3cEG/2/

I need count all word, including cirillic expressions, not only words in latin. How to do that?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do, but shouldn't `.trim().split(/\s+/).length` do it for every alphabet?

Comment: @Bergi not if OP wants to count a string `"like . . . this"` as 2 words.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

JavaScript (at least the versions most widely used) does not fully support Unicode. That is to say, `\w` matches only Latin letters, decimal digits, and underscores (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`), and `\b` matches the boundary the between a word character and and a non-word character.

To find all words in an input string using Latin or Cyrillic, you'd have to do something like this:

```
.match(/[\wа-я]+/ig); // where а is the Cyrillic а.
```

Or if you prefer:

```
.match(/[\w\u0430-\u044f]+/ig);
```

Of course this will probably mean you need to tweak your code a little bit, since here it will match all words rather than word boundaries. Note that `[а-я]` matches any letter in the 'basic Cyrillic alphabet' as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script_in_Unicode#Basic_Cyrillic_alphabet). To match letters outside of this range, you can modify the character set as necessary to include those letters, e.g. to also match the Russian Ё/ё, use `[а-яё]`.

Also note that your triple-bracket pattern can be simplified to:

```
.replace(/\[{3}[^]]*]{3}/g, '')
```

Alternatively, you might want to look at the [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) project—which is an open-source project to add new features to the base JavaScript regular expression engine—and its [Unicode](http://xregexp.com/plugins/#unicode) addon.

Comment: I would also suggest /[\wа-яА-Я]+/ig as "а-я" are case sensitive.

Comment: @Zon the `i` at the end makes it case-insensitive. Although I'll grant that there are almost certainly some browsers out there that aren't smart enough to handle matching А-Я in `/[а-я]/i`!

Comment: Like Zon-browser! :)

Comment: In case it helps anyone else, `а-я` was being encoded (presumably by my editor) such that it rendered no matches in the REGEX. Using the unicode character range instead solved the problem.

Answer (score 8):

Beware of using range of cyrillic letters, it may contain unnecessary characters within.
There is bulletproof regexp contains only cyrillic letters:

```
/^[аАбБвВгГдДеЕёЁжЖзЗиИйЙкКлЛмМнНоОпПрРсСтТуУфФхХцЦчЧшШщЩъЪыЫьЬэЭюЮяЯ]+$/
```

Comment: What characters in `\p{Cyrillic}+` are unwanted?

Comment: @MrVocabulary `\p{Cyrillic}+` is invalid regexp. Did you mean `\p{IsCyrillic}+`?

Comment: No, I am using it the way I wrote it and it works in Ruby and Notepad++. It's also mentioned like that in multiple specifications: https://regular-expressions.mobi/unicode.html?wlr=1

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work in in Notepad++. Anyways, to quote a fragment: *Perl and the JGsoft flavor allow you to use \p{IsLatin} instead of \p{Latin}. The "Is" syntax is useful for distinguishing between scripts and blocks, as explained in the next section. PCRE, PHP, and XRegExp do not support the "Is" prefix.*

Comment: I misunderstood how regexp works. I messed up with global flag and @p-s-w-g answer is absolutely correct. Sorry for my answer.

Comment: Of course this is not full cyrillic alphabet. You forgot Ukrainian and Belarusian characters, not mentioning Balcan Slavonic characters or legacy alphabet with ѣ, ѧ, ѩ, ѵ, ꙋ / ѹ etc. Also remember of few dozens of cyrillic alphabets for non-slavonic languages (turkic, mongolian, uralic, tungusic, chukotko-kamchatkan and so forth).

Whatever it was, here is the real full list of all modern cyrillic characters used in modern slavonic languages:

АБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯЁЂЃЄЅІЇЈЉЊЋЌЎЏҐабвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяёђѓєѕіїјљњћќўџґ

Comment: If you use `\p{Alphabetic}` or `\p{Letter}` you will include other alphabetic letters from other languages such as Greek and Arabic.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to the most upvoted answer, you could do it like this:

`.match(/[\w\p{sc=Cyrillic}]+/ug);`

You can read more about it [here](https://javascript.info/regexp-unicode#example-chinese-hieroglyphs).

Answer (score 1):

You can add the **/u** flag, which allows you to work with Unicode.

When you add this flag, your example works.