# Need assistance with regexp and cyrillic

Tags: php, regex, unicode

i´ve got the following Problem

i have a regular expression i did not made myself:

```
"|(?!<.*?)\b$old_text\b(?![^<>]*?>)|s"
```

it wonderfully finds $old_text in $text

but if $old_text for example is

```
"ОртоЦентр"
```

it wont find it

i´m sure its all about the `/b` boundaries reffering to

[Regular expression with the cyrillic alphabet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18471159/regular-expression-with-the-cyrillic-alphabet)

so i tried to adapt it like

```
\[wа-я]+$old_text\[wа-я]+
```

or

```
\wа-я$old_text\wа-я
```

also tried sth. like using unicode range:

```
|(?!<.*?)\x{0410}$old_text\x{042F}(?![^<>]*?>)|
```

also tried this Cyrillic thing but i´m sur i´m not using correct:

```
"|(?!<.*?)\b{Cyrillic}$old_text\b{Cyrillic}(?![^<>]*?>)|si"
```

maybe this rather is the right direction ? 
but hey all dont work, can some genius pls. assist me ? 
thanks in advance

update:

```
"|(?!<.*?)\p{Cyrillic}+\b$old_text\b(?![^<>]*?>)|si"
```

update, heres the php-code:

```
$text = "bar foo <p> barfoo </p> foobar ОртоЦентр bar bar";
$old_text = "ОртоЦентр";
$new_text = '<a href="http://foo.bar">ОртоЦентр</a>';
$limit = '-1';

$replaced = preg_replace( "|(?!<.*?)(\p{Cyrillic}+$old_text\b)(?![^<>]*?>)|si", $new_text, $text, $limit );
```

Comment: You need to initialize the Cyrillic with \p : `\p{Cyrillic}+`

Comment: @l'L'l could you explain how and where ? i tried like in my update of question and some other points but have no idea

Comment: Sure, what is your final output supposed to look like though? Try this `"|(?!<.*?)\p{Cyrillic}+(?![^<>]*?>)|si"`, or `"|(?!<.*?)\b\p{Cyrillic}+$old_text\b(?![^<>]*?>)|si"`

Comment: @l'L'l it replaces a word with a link, example: changes `ОртоЦентр` to `<a  href="http://foo.bar">ОртоЦентр</a>` and should also work for non cyrillic words

Comment: @l'L'l does not seem to work :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the question, you want to replace such as `ОртоЦентр` but also `aaaОртоЦентрzzz` with `<a href="http://foo.bar">...</a>` where `...` is the matching word.

From your inital regex it looks like this should be only done "outside tags".

To work with unicode need to specify the `u` (PCRE_UTF8) [modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php). Both, pattern and input are expected to be valid UTF-8 then. My following example also uses the `i` caseless modifier.

Would [skip](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Special-Backtracking-Control-Verbs) the tags: `<[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)` or `|` match the word with `*` any amount of `\p{L}` [unicode letters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) before and after: `\b\p{L}*word\p{L}*\b` and [capture](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). A sample-pattern could be:

```
~<[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|\b(\p{L}*ОртоЦентр\p{L}*)\b~ui
```

[Test at regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/rX6iL3/1) (see explanation on the right side)

---

And a PHP-sample with variables:

```
$txt = "bar foo <p> barfoo </p> foobar aОртоЦентрz bar bar";

$w = "ОртоЦентр";

$s = '~<[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|\b(\p{L}*'.preg_quote($w,'~').'\p{L}*)\b~ui';
$r = '<a href="http://foo.bar">\1</a>';

$replaced = preg_replace($s, $r, $txt);
```

[Test at eval.in](https://eval.in/204336)

Comment: @johnSmith You're welcome! Glad it works out for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Using this pattern (or similar) should be able to do what you want:

```
/(?!<.*?)([\\p{Cyrillic}]+)(?![^<>]*?\\>)/umi
```

Code:

```
<?php

$regex = "/(?!<.*?)([\\p{Cyrillic}]+)(?![^<>]*?\\>)/umi";
$strng = "bar foo <p> barfoo </p> foobar ОртоЦентр bar bar\n";
$subst = '<a href="http://foo.bar">$1</a>';
$limit = '-1';

$result = preg_replace($regex, $subst, $strng, $limit);

echo $result . "\n";

?>
```

**Result:**

```
bar foo <p> barfoo </p> foobar <a href="http://foo.bar">ОртоЦентр</a> bar bar
```

**Example(s):**

- **http://ideone.com/vl9Nf1**
- **http://regex101.com/r/nG6nL7/1**

NOTE: If you have strings that are more than one word `(i.e. Россия прохладно)` a slight change to the pattern is needed:

```
/(?!<.*?)([\p{Cyrillic}]+.+[\p{Cyrillic}]+)(?![^<>]*?\\>)/umi
```

Comment: this seems to escape the $ ?

Comment: dont know this wheter replaces the cyrillic nor non-cyrillice using: `"|(?!<.*?)(\p{Cyrillic}+$old_text\b)(?![^<>]*?>)|si"` , maybe i forgot to mention that $old_text is a php variable

Comment: If you post your php code I can take a better look. Hard to know exactly what is happening without it. Are you wanting to capture only Cyrillic?

Comment: Updated the Question with the code-example and many thanks to your effords

Comment: hm i dont really know what you mean, the variables and preg_match are exactly like in my update and it works with the initial regex and non cyrillic word