# Adding regex for only Cyrillic letters and white spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18471159/regular-expression-with-the-cyrillic-alphabet/18471465) and many other posts, questions and articles, but whaterver I do I cannot make the validation for `only-cyrillic` works.

Here is my validation check:

```
$.validator.addMethod("onlycyrillic", function (value, element, param) {
    var inputValue = $.trim(value);
    var cyrillicValidationRegex = RegExp("/[\wа-я]+/s+/ig");
    var testResult = cyrillicValidationRegex.test(inputValue);
    return testResult;
});
```

Comment: As explained in the answer you linked to,` [\wа-я]` is for Latin or Russian characters.  
Remove `\w`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To validate a string only consisting of Cyrillic letters and whitespace chars you may use

```
/^[\u0400-\u0484\u0487-\u052F\u1C80-\u1C88\u1D2B\u1D78\u2DE0-\u2DFF\uA640-\uA69F\uFE2E\uFE2F\s]*$/
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[\u0400-\u0484\u0487-\u052F\u1C80-\u1C88\u1D2B\u1D78\u2DE0-\u2DFF\uA640-\uA69F\uFE2E\uFE2F\s]*` - 0 or more Cyrillic letters or whitespaces (see the [chars included here](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5Cp%7BCyrillic%7D&g=&i=))
- `$` - end of string.

JS test:

```js
var s = "Меня зовут Витя";
var cyrillicValidationRegex = /^[\u0400-\u0484\u0487-\u052F\u1C80-\u1C88\u1D2B\u1D78\u2DE0-\u2DFF\uA640-\uA69F\uFE2E\uFE2F\s]*$/;
console.log(cyrillicValidationRegex.test(s));
```

And with the ECMAScript 2018+ compliant regex, you can shorten the pattern to `/^[\p{Script=Cyrl}\s]*$/u`:

```js
const s = "Меня зовут Витя";
const cyrillicValidationRegex = /^[\p{Script=Cyrl}\s]*$/u;
console.log(cyrillicValidationRegex.test(s));
```